# How do i change theme of eclipse while writing/editing files(java file/html file/jsp file etc)?

Tags: eclipse

I mean to say while developing application in eclipse.

If i write java program i get key words in brown color variables in blue color background is white color.

Is there any way to change the font color and background of  eclipse IDE editors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window - Preferences - General - Appearance - Colors and Fonts, 
Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Syntax Coloring